# Какая технология/API осуществляет работу с сайтами в Java?

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Я написал для клиента (страховая контора) Desktop-приложение с бизнес-логикой - учет выпущенных полисов, генерирование счетов, отчетов, рассылки SMS и Email и т.д. Все это написано на JavaFX. Теперь клиент хочет, чтобы программа могла сама выпускать страховые полисы.
Обычно полисы выпускаются работниками, которые проделывают все нужные операции вручную - заходят на сайт нужной страховой кампании, в нужном месте логинятся, далее проходят по нужным ссылкам, заполняют текстовые поля, производят поиски автомобилей и клиентов по рег. номерам и личным кодам, выбирают нужные значения в чекбоксах и т.д., в конце получая PDF-документы - ну в общем обычная работа с порталом.
Теперь программа должна сама заходить на сайты страховых кампаний и проделывать всю эту ручную работу - залогиниться, нажать нужную ссылку на сайте (выбор типа полиса), заполнить все данные, нажать кнопку "выпустить полис" и если все поля заполнены корректно и не вылезло сообщений об ошибке - скачать сгенерированный PDF-документ. Все данные, которые необходимы для выпуска нового полиса, уже есть в базе данных написанной программы.
Я совершенно не разбираюсь в сетевом программировании Java, и в общем-то я даже не могу корректно составить поисковый запрос на эту тему, чтобы начать этому учиться. Как вообще называется эта область программирования? Я пытался изучать информацию по запросам "java работа с сайтами", "работа с http java", "java networking" и в общем понял, что информации много, а что именно смотреть - не совсем понятно. Было бы время, я бы разобрался, но мне решение нужно принимать быстро. Пожалуйста, подскажите, куда смотреть в первую очередь.

Чтобы примерно представлять, как все это выглядит - прикрепляю скрины (данные публикуются с разрешения владельцев).
Так выглядит написанная программа (Git https://github.com/DannPeterson/Insa):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Так выглядит среднестатистический портал страховой кампании, где происходит генерация полисов. Сначала логин: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Далее выбор типа полиса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Далее мы первый раз вбиваем данные (вбиваю свои для примера), жмем "calculate":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Появляется возможность выбора страхового периода, выбираем нужный:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Далее, если все было сделано правильно, нажимаем кнопку "IssuePolicy":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Портал загружает нам PDF, с которым мне уже понятно что делать дальше. А непонятно, как проделать всю эту работу на сайте автоматически.

Comment: это называется Java Enterprise Edition или Java EE.

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/search?source=hp&ei=K3DhW7bHH8rKrgT_nJXwAg&btnG=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA&q=Java+EE&oq=etrt&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l8j0i10i1k1j0.93031.93283.0.93453.8.5.0.0.0.0.168.168.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..7.1.167.0...0.3Hi2tVJW7ic

Comment: Все зависит от того есть ли у страховой компании API. Если есть то нужно получить документацию и дальше действовать в зависимости от того что в ней. Если нет, то вас ждет дорога полная боли и страдания.

Comment: @talex насколько я понял - API нет, все придется проделывать вручную.

Comment: Скорее всего, вам придется столкунться со Spring, Html, javascript. Всё зависит от того, что конкретно будет необходимо компании. Проще, взять готовый движок, например, Bitrix... я его не хвалю, он он мне первый в голову пришёл, потому что о нём тьма рекламы

Comment: @DaniilPeterson Если нет API то есть два плохих варианта: взять selenium и повторить на нем шаги которые делаются в ручную или отдебажить сайт и посмотреть какие запросы идут на сервер и пытаться их имитировать при помощи любого HTTP клиента. Первое проще, второе будет работать стабильнее.

Comment: @Dred Может быть я неправильно выразился, сказав "программа должна сама выпускать страховые полисы". Программа не должна выпускать полисы, она должна просто автоматически проделывать всю ручную работу на сайтах страховых кампаний, получая в конце тот же результат, что и работник.

Comment: @DaniilPeterson, То есть, клиент заходит на сайт, вводит свои данные и жмет Отправить, а сайт генерирует полис и выводит его обратно на сайт, либо шлет на почту, верно?

Comment: @Dred если упрощенно, то да, так и есть. Когда все данные на странице портала подготовлены и нажимается кнопка "выпустить полис", то появляется возможность скачать все необходимые ПДФ документы, нажав на кнопку.

Comment: Можно попробовать встроенный браузер и в него передавать JavaScript команды: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на мой сумбурный вопрос: для автоматизации/имитации работы браузера обычно используют Selenium с драйвером, оборачивающим какой-либо браузер.

Спасибо @Dred за помощь в осознании того, что мне действительно было нужно.
Извиняюсь перед @talex за то, что пропустил его комментарий с правильным ответом.

Answer (score 0):

В теории, если ваше приложение качественно написано, то его можно немного изменить, чтобы оно делало всё самостоятельно,а не по кликам мышки человека.

Создать еще модуль, который должен будет брать данные с сайта и посылать их в ваше приложение либо добавить этот модуль внутри текущего вашего приложения, но я бы разделил. В теории, этот модуль может и быть сайтом, всё зависит от того, будете ли вы всё тянуть на себе.

После, запустить это всё на каком-нибудь сервере, допустим servicemix или Tomcat, чтобы ваши приложения могли работать круглогодично. 
  В принципе это всё, что вам требуется.

Если брать более детальную реализацию, то нужно настраивать Security, Rest/Soap или как у вас будет работать ваше приложение с вложениями.

Таким образом, вкратце, вам необходимо и достаточно, HTML,CSS, servicemix/Tomcat, REST/SOAP, Security (а оно очень важно, так как вы работаете с личными данными людей), ну и конечно же БД, скорее всего реляционная, можно MySQL,postgreSQL... на ваш выбор.

**P.S.**

В принципе, если сотрудники всё заполняют сами, вам нужно, сделать класс ( объект ) приложения, который будет содержать все поля. Ну, либо класс, который будет собирать все это воедино.

Когда срок окончания полиса будет близок, надо отправить клиенту смс, хочет ли он продливать страховку или нет ( вдруг автомобиль продан).

Если у сайтов нет API, это будет сложно. Вам нужно будет писать парсер и постояно отслеживать то, чтобы на сайте не менялась структура тегов. Selenium вам поможет для тестов вашего парсера, либо пробуйте сразу из приложения.
Если сайты не ваши и нет API, то JSON вам и не нужен, просто вставлять туда String.

В итоге, ваш парсер, каким-либо образом находит поле, например Name и туда пишет ваше имя.
Например,

```
class Policy {
String name;
String surname;
........ другие поля
//setters and getters
}
```

парсер в таком случае берет из вашего объекта `getName()` и все. Перед тем как лезть на сайт, лучше подготовить всю информацию уже в рамках 1 объекта, чтобы не лазить каждый раз в БД.
При нажатии Submit, нужно смотреть как сайт отправляет полис и уже его таким образом забирать. Выкачивать, заходить на почту и оттуда забирать, сохраняться как картинку/pdf....

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Скорее нужен модуль, который при помощи существующих в программе данных (они как раз в MySql) проделает всю работу на сайте страховой кампании и результат этой работы (файл PDF) загрузит в программу - эта часть у меня уже написана, сейчас программа как раз работает с этими PDF. Я немного уточнил запрос и добавил несколько скриншотов к первоначальному запросу.

Comment: @DaniilPeterson Странно то, что пишете для немцев, а вопрос на русском сайте задаете, а не на английском :-)  Немного не понятно, откуда берутся данные, которые программа должна сама на сайтах искать? кто их в базу должен заносить? Если это делают люди, почему они сразу не могут делать это на сайте? А то получается люди вносят сначала всё в программу, а потом программа ищет всё на сайте

Comment: это эстонский) По поводу второго вопроса - программа для страхового бюро, а не для страховой кампании. Т.е. это маленькая контора, в которую приходят люди и спрашивают -  "а сделайте мне страховку в самой подходящей для меня страховой кампании" - и работники бюро ищут самый дешевый вариант среди всех возможных страховых фирм, выпускают полис, отадают клиенту, и заносят информацию о полисе в написанную мной для этого бюро программу. Когда по данным программы подходит срок окончания полиса, она должна сделать его автоматически - данные об автомобиле и личный код клиента уже в есть.

Comment: Добавил немного ответ после P.S. Но это так, моё личное мнение и, мне кажется, если сайтов очень много, то ваша работа будет стоить ооооочень много, чтобы сделать парсеры для каждого сайта. Если сайт изменится, то к вам будут обращаться, чтобы поправить парсер. Можете почитать про [crawler](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-basic-web-crawler-example/) как пример. Может быть будет полезен. Я как-то сайт с рецептами парсил, так намучился, но он был 1, а у вас будет много разных.

Comment: Объекты Полис, Клиент и все остальные уже сделаны в программе, можно посмотреть на Гите https://github.com/DannPeterson/Insa/blob/master/src/ee/insa/datamodel/Policy.java , парсинг ПДФ-ов в объекты Полис и Клиент так же уже написаны, и все это работает с небольшой базой SQLite на 4 компах. Насчет постоянного слежения за изменениями на сайте - это да, уже столкнулся, страховые кампании периодически меняют стиль своих ПДФ-файлов, и иногда приходится подправлять пдф-парсеры, так что к такому я впринципе готов, как и кошелек клиента.

Comment: СМС и подтвержение необходимости продления - все это уже тоже реализовано - отмечатеся в программе в нужных местах. Как я и говорил, весь оставшийся вопрос в том, чтобы проделать работу на сайтах страховых кампаний автоматически.

Comment: А как у вас приложение сейчас работает? На 4 компах, но как они в БД льют? Пользователь приходит на работу, включает комп и включает программу на каждом из компов?  А как БД работает?
Вам осталось только "поднять" сервис на каком-нибудь сервере. Настроить в программе таймер, чтобы она раз в сутки смотрела в БД, когда полисы заканчиваются и по ним лезла на сайты, парсила, вносила всю информацию.

Comment: База данных находится на серверном комьютере конторы, который включен 24/7, на каждом компе работника установлена написанная мной программа-клиент, которая для работы постоянно связывается с этой базой (JDBC). В базе записывается все, что выпускается конторой - для внутреннего учета, бухгалтерии, ну и вообще для удобства. В нее встроена разнообразная аналитика по базе - какие полисы кончаются, рассылка автонапоминаний клиентам о подходящих сроках и много всякого другого.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92368/discussion-between-dred-and-daniil-peterson).